# Using jQuery to generate a href inside an anchor tag with content from xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

So I got a problem with my code, and after hours of googling I cant seem to find a solution..

My code looks like this:

```
$(function() {
           $.ajax({
               method: "GET",
               url: "xml/rss.xml",
               dataType: "xml",
               success: function(result){
                   $(result).find("rss channel").each(function () {
                      var channel = $(this).find("title").text();

                       $(".rss ul").append(
                           $("<li />").append(
                                $("<a href='#'>", {
                                    text: channel
                                }, "</a>")
                           )
                       );
                   });
               },
               error: function() {
                   alert("fail!");
               }
           }); 
        });
```

Now here's the problem, when I run it like this the  tag receives the href attribute, but the xml text doesn't appear within the list-elements.

If I remove the href="#" like this:

```
$(".rss ul").append(
    $("<li />").append(
        $("<a>", {
            text: channel
        }, "</a>")
    )
);
```

The text from the xml file shows up in my list, but the anchors are not clickable. Am I using the wrong code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of your `a` tag is incorrect.  Try this instead -

```
$("<a>", {
  text: channel,
  href: '#'
})
```